# Rudin's statement of Hahn-Banach's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Rudin's statement of the Hahn-Banach theorem in *Functional Analysis* (Theorem 3.2) involves a linear form $f$ defined on some subspace of a real vector space, and which is bounded by a sublinear function, as usual. But the specific hypotheses assumed about this sublinear function are:

> 1. $p(x+y) \leq p(x)+p(y)$
> 2. For non-negative $t$, $p(tx)=p(x)$ (!!)

Shouldn't it be $p(tx)=tp(x)$? The proof seems to implicitly use the latter condition, and not condition (2) quoted above. But I can't find references to any errata online.

Is the theorem still true with this different assumption on $p$? If so, how do you deduce from it that it also works when $p$ is a semi-norm? Rudin basically just says that if $p$ is a semi-norm, the result is "contained in Theorem 3.2", but a semi norm does not satisfy $p(tx)=p(x)$.

Comment: Typos sneak in the worst possible places.

Comment: Question of weakening hypothesis, which is always rewarding in mathematics?

Comment: The assumption that $p(tx)=p(x)$ for all $t \ge 0$ makes it easier because $p(x)=p(0)$ for all $x$. Definitely simplifies everything, but it's not very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is a typo. I had a look at a French translation of the book today, and it has $p(tx)=tp(x)$, as expected.